# Redirect old articles to new articles .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This is a pretty specific question, so no answer on Stack or Google could help me.

Recently I've moved my blog from www.example.com to www.example.com/blog.
On www.example.com I have a landing page, so I need it to be working as well.

I would like to redirect all www.example.com/YYYY/MM/DD/article-name to www.example.com/blog/YYYY/MM/DD/article-name, but at the same time to keep www.example.com intact.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :)

```
RedirectMatch "^/(\d){4}/(\d){2}/(\d){2}/(.+)" "^/blog/$1/$2/$3/$4"
```

If this doesn't do the job, the following line definitely will:

```
RedirectMatch "^/(\d)+/(\d)+/(\d)+/(.+)" "^/blog/$1/$2/$3/$4"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm sorry, it's not working. Tried both with or without HTTPS

Comment: That is suprising, to say the least oO But ok, let's find out what I got wrong :) You want to enter www.example.com/YYYY/MM/DD/article-name where 'article-name' is the same as 'article-name' in the target?! And it should be rewritten to www.example.com/blog/YYYY/MM/DD/article-name but doesn't? What do you get when you call, let's say http://example.com/2017/04/01/article101 ? I assume it doesn't give you http://example.com/blog//2017/04/01/article101

Comment: I get "Requested url not found".

Comment: ok, but can you copy&paste your target-uri from your browser?

Comment: http://www.mihaicosti.ro/2012/07/21/13-editie-i-d-fest-luat-sfarsit/ to https://www.mihaicosti.ro/blog/2012/07/21/13-editie-i-d-fest-luat-sfarsit/ (SSL is forced from the apache conf file)

Comment: To me that seems exactly like what you describbed?! Can you tell me where the request mihaicosti.ro/2012/07/21/13-editie-i-d-fest-luat-sfarsit should end up?

Comment: It should end up on the second link, which is working because it is supposed to work.
So, it should end up on https://www.mihaicosti.ro/blog/2012/07/21/13-editie-i-d-fest-luat-sfarsit/

Comment: sry, classical misunderstanding. thought the URLs you posted where your test and didn't see where it went wrong. But now I tested it myself and got it. on a sidenote: I'd suggest you put 'ServerTokens Prod' into your main Apache config, which will prevent such detailed information shown to the user: 
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at www.mihaicosti.ro Port 443

Comment: Will do. I tested the regexp you wrote and it does not detect the link. But I wrote this and it's detecting, but how do I write it for apache?
RedirectMatch "\/(\d*)\/(\d*)\/(\d*)\/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)\/" - * insert redirect query here *

Comment: I did it :D You can try it
RedirectMatch ^\/(\d*)\/(\d*)\/(\d*)\/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)\/ /blog/$1/$2/$3/$4

Answer (score 0):

Solved with Regular Expression inspired from the above answer from Hello Fishy(Thank you)
RedirectMatch ^/(\d*)/(\d*)/(\d*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)/ /blog/$1/$2/$3/$4

Comment: That also redirects /987/22222222//Check1Me2Out since there are no specifications about the amount of digits. Even zero digits are allowed with * --> + requires at least one digit

Comment: That doesn't really bother me, it would just end up on a 404 page of the blog. But yeah, I see your point.

Comment: Alright, if it's good enough for you, it's good enough for me :D